# To translate "disease", what is the difference among "enfermedad", "dolencia" and "afección"?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario-médico

I have translated **disease** into Spanish. There are three translations there. I am studying the difference between them.

- [**dolencia**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=E5FHcSm): "Indisposición, achaque, enfermedad." or "Infamia, deshonra.".
- [**enfermedad**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=FHA3D3L): "Alteración más o menos grave de la salud." or "Pasión dañosa o alteración en lo moral o espiritual." or "Anormalidad dañosa en el funcionamiento de una institución, colectividad."
- [**afección**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=0w6yMWv): "Med. enfermedad. Afección pulmonar, catarral, reumática."

Hypothesis: dolencia=ache (dolor de cabeza), enfermedad=disease, enfermedad can also refer to bad functioning of an organization, afección=inflammation

Am I right? What is the difference?

Answer (score 1):

You are partially right and the differences are subtle.

In general use, *enfermedad* is normally something easier to diagnose, while *dolencia* has to do with some kind of chronic pain.

I found an article explaining this. [Diferencia entre enfermedad y dolencia](http://medicinabiologicapuebla.com.mx/frameset.php?url=/blog_42332_DIFERENCIA-ENTRE-ENFERMEDAD-Y-DOLENCIA.html):

> La enfermedad pertenece al cuerpo físico y generalmente se considera que es causada por elementos externos como virus, bacterias y otros. La dolencia es algo interno poco fácil de explicar. Es como un sentirse mal sin motivo aparente, es algo que se siente en lo interno, como un cansancio emocional, un abatimiento, una debilidad  inexplicable; ello se debe a un quiebre en la energía esencial del cuerpo cuántico

This sounds a bit philosophical, doesn't it? So let's check yet another one of this kind in [Dolencia, enfermedad, afección](http://www.chasque.net/frontpage/relacion/9904/dolencia.htm):

> 1) **Illness** (inglés), Kranksein (alemán) podría traducirse por **Dolencia** o Malestar en castellano. Es aquella forma bajo la cual el propio enfermo sufre su enfermedad, es un ámbito subjetivo en el cual el afectado magnifica o minimiza su padecimiento;
>
> 2) **Disease** (inglés), Krankheit (alemán) podrían equipararse a **Enfermedad**, en tanto entidad mórbida que es reconocida por los médicos. Las noxas eran clasificadas como "lesiones" anatomopatológicas en el siglo pasado, como "disfunciones" o "agresiones" orquestadas por agentes exteriores (v.g. infecciones). La enfermedad como tal reconoce un agente patógeno, una fisiopatología, una historia natural y una terapéutica -a veces inhallable. Esta perspectiva nos coloca a ojos vista en el ámbito de lo objetivo;
>
> 3) **Sickness** (inglés), por último, encuentra un equivalente castellano en el término **Afección**. Refiere a la manera en que una sociedad le atribuye a un individuo una cierta enfermedad, a la manera en que una sociedad reconoce a ciertas condiciones como enfermedad y a ciertos individuos como enfermos. Esto significa que los profanos determinan, aprecian y cuantifican el apoyo, la conmiseración o estigma que le implicará su condición de enfermo.

Comment: What should I call a liver disease? Is it "enfermedad del higado" or  "afección del higado"?

Comment: @cornejo probably _enfermedad del hígado_ or even _enfermedad hepática_ (_hepático_ refers to the liver).